# More on linear algebra vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am continuing on my journey of trying to understand vector subspaces.

**Question:** Let $F(-\infty,\infty)$ be the set of all real-value functions defined at each x in the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Show the odd functions $U=\{f(x)|f(-x)=-f(x), f(x) \in F(-\infty,\infty)\}$ is a subspace of $F(-\infty,\infty)$

**My Answer**: let **f**=f(x) and **g**=g(x).

**Under operation of addition**

(**f**+**g**)(x)=f(x)+g(x)

(**f**+**g**)(-x)=f(-x)+g(-x) therefore where f(-x)=-f(x), (**f**+**g**)(-x)=-f(x)-g(x) so the operation of addition holds.

**For scalar multiplication**

(k**f**)(x)=kf(x)

(k**f**(-x))=kf(-x) so where f(-x)=-f(x); (k**f**)(-x)=-kf(x) so scalar multiplication holds true.

Therefore U is a subspace of $F(-\infty,\infty)$.

I think I am missing something though in terms of 'the odd fuctions'.

Thanks

Comment: You have shown that the sum of two odd functions is an odd function and that a scalar times an odd function is still odd. The only thing you need to do is show that the zero function is odd.

Comment: Show the set is non-empty

Answer (score 0):

Short of showing that the collection of odd functions is nonempty (which is easy since $f\equiv 0$ is odd) this looks good.

For future reference, the most efficient way to prove that a nonempty subset $U$ of a vector space $V$ is a subspace is with the [one-step vector subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test). In short, the test states that $U$ is a subspace if and only if $\lambda u+v\in U$ whenever $u,v\in U$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb R$.

Thus, to prove that the subset $U$ of $F(-\infty,\infty)$ consisting of odd functions is a subspace of $F(-\infty,\infty)$ begin by noting that $f\equiv 0$ is odd so that $U$ is non-empty. Then let $f,g\in U$ and that $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. It follows that
$$
(\lambda f+g)(-x)=\lambda f(-x)+g(-x)=-\lambda f(x)-g(x)=-(\lambda f+g)(x)
$$
so that $\lambda f+g\in U$. This proves that $U$ is indeed a subspace.